# How to make the coordinate user interactive in core plot

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, graph, core-plot

I am kind of trying to get the flow of core plot. I have implemented the graph with my x-axis time(hours) and y axis to be some values. Now, i wanted to make each coordinate user interactive, such that, if the user touches each coordinate, I should be able to get the X and Y value of it. I also came across this question while searching for some tips.[How to make the coordinate of a graph user interactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158059/how-to-make-the-coordinate-of-a-graph-user-interactive) But unfortunately, I couldn't find any stubs as mentioned in the answers like mouseOrFingerDownAtPoint.

It would be really great if some one helps me find out, where I should implement these functions in the core plot framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interaction methods have been renamed to `pointingDevice...Event`. See the `CPResponder` docs for info.

All of the plots can be configured to respond to touches. You implement the corresponding delegate protocol in your controller and set the delegate property of the plot. The delegate method will tell you the data index of the point that was touched. You can use that index to find the coordinates in your data set. Look at the example programs--several of them demonstrate the plot delegate.

Comment: Can u please explain me little detail. I got the point where u mentioned that the pointing device was the thing it was renamed to. but I think, this would be responding to the dragging the entire core plot area around the screen.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want the user to be able to select points on the plot, see my answer above. CPTestApp (the Mac version) demonstrates selecting points in scatter and bar plots in Controller.m and SelectionDemoController.m. If you want to be able to interact with any arbitrary point in the plot area, that's a different question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric...! I was breaking my head the entire day... U made it so simple...! Working so great and implemented the thing which I wanted to, having this as base.